# How to add the LibreOffice StartCenter to the dash

Tags: libreoffice, gnome-dash

Fresh install of ubuntu 20.10. The LibreOffice-applications, Writer, Calc, Math, ... can be easily added to or removed from the dash. How can I add the LibreOffice StartCenter to the dash?

I opened Writer and closed the document => The StartCenter shows up. If I try to pin the StartCenter to the dash, it disappears as soon as I close LibreOffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-startcenter.desktop
```

Look for the line:

```
NotShowIn=GNOME;
```

And comment it out by placing `#` in front, so it becomes:

```
#NotShowIn=GNOME;
```

Answer (score 0):

same file but change:
NoDisplay=true

to:
NoDisplay=false

logout and log back in.